# How to generate *.f90 files from *.F90 files in gfortran?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have a small fortran program with some pre-processor directives written in a *.F90 file. Now, I would like to generate a *.f90 fortran file from it, which removes all the extra code in the *.F90 file corresponding to the other non-activated directives.

In pgifortran, all I have to do is :

```
pgf90 -F file_name.F90
```

And that is it! It produces a *.f90 file having the lines relevant to the active directives.

How can I do this in gfortran?

Comment: gfortran has the `-E` option.

Comment: You can convert any source file with cpp, regardless of language. This will omit any preprocessor symbols defined by the Fortran compiler, of course.

Comment: @francescalus : Thank you for your input! It worked!

Comment: @Jeff : Thank you for your input! It was very useful!

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] to get more attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## GNU Fortran options

See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Preprocessing-Options.html for full details, but you may observe that the option `-E` preprocesses `foo.F90` to `stdout` (you can, of course, pipe it to e.g. `foo.f90`).

The `-E` option is valid for the GNU compiler front-ends in general, and works for C, C++ and Fortran.

While preprocessing is enabled by default for files with the extentions `.fpp`, `.FPP`, `.F`, `.FOR`, `.FTN`, `.F90`, `.F95`, `.F03` or `.F08`, you can enable it manually with `-cpp`.  You can also disable it manually with `-nocpp`.

## Example Program

```
      program main
      implicit none
#ifdef USER_MACRO
      print*,'USER_MACRO was defined'
#endif
#ifdef __GFORTRAN__
      print*,'I am GNU Fortran (aka gfortran)!'
#endif
#ifdef __GNUC__
      print*,'I am GNU C (or its preprocessor)!'
#endif
      end program main
```

#### Result from GNU C preprocessor (`cpp`)

```
$ cpp -E fpp.F90 
# 1 "fpp.F90"
# 1 "<built-in>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 3
# 324 "<built-in>" 3
# 1 "<command line>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 2
# 1 "fpp.F90" 2
      program main
      implicit none







      print*,'I am GNU C (or its preprocessor)!'

      end program main
```

#### Result from GNU Fortran

```
$ gfortran -E fpp.F90 
# 1 "fpp.F90"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "fpp.F90"
      program main
      implicit none




      print*,'I am GNU Fortran (aka gfortran)!'


      print*,'I am GNU C (or its preprocessor)!'

      end program main
```

Obviously, you can see how user-defined symbols are preprocessed, too:

```
$ gfortran -E -DUSER_MACRO fpp.F90 
# 1 "fpp.F90"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "fpp.F90"
      program main
      implicit none

      print*,'USER_MACRO was defined'


      print*,'I am GNU Fortran (aka gfortran)!'


      print*,'I am GNU C (or its preprocessor)!'

      end program main
```

### Result from Intel Fortran

In case it is of interest, Intel compilers support the same options as GCC:

```
$ ifort -E -DUSER_MACRO fpp.F90 
# 1 "fpp.F90"
      program main
      implicit none

      print*,'USER_MACRO was defined'

# 8

# 11

      end program main
```

### Preprocessing with IBM XL Fortran

The IBM XL Fortran man pages have the full details, but it is important to note that preprocessor symbols must be provided via `-WF,-DUSER_MACRO` instead of `-DUSER_MACRO`.

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful!